# Update the changed value in the physical XML File

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to update certain attributes of my xml file using javascript.
I am able to set new value by calling `setAttribute()` method, but unable to reflect it in the physical file.

I am very much new to html javascript. Please help.
 Below I am posting my HTML as well as xml file code.

**Html code:**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://10.21.64.222/LoadBreakSwitch/vbn.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();

    function myFunction(xml) {
        var x, i, txt, xmlDoc; 
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        txt = "";

        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Ping");

         x[0].setAttribute("CommValue","1122222");
            txt +=x[0].getAttribute("CommValue")+"<br>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**xml file code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LBSCommands>
  <Ping Commkey="A3070000AA00A4" CommValue="A309008001043101A4"/>
  <Frequency Commkey="A3070300AD00A4" CommValue="A309038001013101A4"/>
  <SwitchStatus Commkey="A3071D01C800A4" CommValue="A3091D8101014C01A4"/>
  <SwitchLockStatus Commkey="A3071E01C900A4" CommValue="A3091E8101004C01A4"/>
  <SetFrequency01 Commkey="A308130001BF00A4" CommValue="A309038001013101A4"/>
</LBSCommands>
```

Comment: If you want to persist modification server side, you have to serialize your updated xml and send it back to the server with an ajax request for example. Of course, your server have to be extended to support this new call : extract the updated file from the request and save it.

Comment: @ArnaudDevelay: Thank you. Can you please elaborate  a bit?